# python 3 csv list writing issue - current csv structure changes when I add new list

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I'm writing a program that stores contacts. Each contact has name, email and phone number. My function to read the file into a list in main works and my function to list works before try to add or delete a contact. When I try to list the contents of the file, after adding or deleting, I get this error:

in listContacts
    print(str(i + 1) + "." + row)
TypeError: must be str, not list

I've gone into the file after trying to add a contact (with name, email, phone) and the file is all wonky. The original contacts now have commas between each letter or number, but the added row is listed correctly.

```
def readContacts():
    contacts = []
    with open(CONTACTS_FILE, newline="") as conFile:
    reader = csv.reader(conFile)
    for row in conFile:
        contacts.append(row)
    return contacts

def writeContacts(contacts):
with open(CONTACTS_FILE, "w", newline="") as conFile:
    writer = csv.writer(conFile)
    writer.writerows(contacts)

def addContacts(contacts):
name = input("Name: ")
email = input("Email: ")
phone = input("Phone: ")
addRow = []
addRow.append(name)
addRow.append(email)
addRow.append(phone)
contacts.append(addRow)
writeContacts(contacts)
print(name + " was added.")
print()

def deleteContacts(contacts):
num = int(input("Number: "))
if num > len(contacts):
    print("Not a valid command. Please try again.")
else:
    delCont = contacts.pop(num - 1)
    writeContacts(contacts)
    print(delCont + " was deleted.")
print()

def listContacts(contacts):
for i in range(len(contacts)):
    row = contacts[i]
    readContacts()
    print(str(i + 1) + "." + row)
print()
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong? Any ideas where I've screwed up?

Thanks!

Comment: Judging by the fact that you append stuff to `addRow`, and then append *that* to `contacts`, by getting `contacts [i]`, you are really getting a list, not a string. Python is having trouble adding a list to a string (`print (str (i + 1) + "." + row)`)

Comment: So how do I fix that? Do I write into the file differently? What I don't understand is why my csv file goes all crazy, with one character of every string in each column, AFTER I add something to the file. But the strings I've added look right in the csv.

Comment: I can't access my computer right now, I can help you troubleshoot in an hour or so. My suggestion right now is that wherever you write to the file, insert a print statement to see *what* you are writing. My understanding is since it happens after you add, it must be in the addContacts function, which passes a list of lists to writeContacts. You might want to manually inspect that list (in the write function) with a print statement.

Comment: To fix the print statement, change `row` to `", ".join (row)`. This will convert a list into a CSV string.

Comment: Thanks for the help Levi! I've got it all worked out!

Comment: Glad I could help!